# Selenium Java: Problem with accessing calendar date element

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, date, calendar

I am learning Selenium (Java) and I am trying to select a specific data from a travel page, 26th March, however the automation mostly fails - ending up showing calendar of next month without the date selected. If trying several times, it also occurred that the calendar stopped on March - but still did not get the date.

Could anyone please help to spot, what I am doing wrong. Many thanks!

```
public class path2usacalendar_new {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/DDD/WebDrivers/chromedriver");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companion"); 

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        // Scroll the Page
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1100)");

        // Click on the Date field
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        WebElement Date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='form-field-travel_comp_date']"));
        // js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", Date);
        Date.click();
        //WebElement month = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='flatpickr-month']"));
        while(!driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='flatpickr-month']")).getText().contains("March"))
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='flatpickr-next-month']")).click();
        }


        int count= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='flatpickr-day ']")).size();


        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            String text=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='flatpickr-day ']")).get(i).getText();
            if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("26"))
            {
                // driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[class*='day']")).get(i).click();
                driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='flatpickr-day ']")).get(i).click();
                System.out.println("The select day is:"+text);
                break;
            }
        }
        String date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='form-field-travel_comp_date']")).getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println("The select date is:"+date);

    }

}
```

Thanks
Niki

I tried to click through the calendar via the while loop until March is visible and then grab the number of days for the particular month and select my day of preference, which is 26 in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the wait time in a while loop Nik.

```
while (!driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='flatpickr-month']")).getText()
    .contains("March")) {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='flatpickr-next-month']")).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Ideally, we don't use Thread.sleep in the java program, instead of that you can use any type of waits present in Selenium utility.

I tried in my local and the program is working fine now.

Comment: Hello Purendra, thanks for help out. The "Thread.sleep(2000)" was actually my first advice that I got as a fix solution. I changed the position, as per your advise, but it is not working for me. The calendar stops at March month, but the date is not selected. This is the output I am getting in eclipse (remark: I do have the chromedriver for 108 version. I have just downloaded it again and put to the path.

Comment: ```SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
Starting ChromeDriver 108.0.5359.71 (1e0e3868ee06e91ad636a874420e3ca3ae3756ac-refs/branch-heads/5359@{#1016}) on port 11397
Only local connections are allowed.```

Comment: ```Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Dec 18, 2022 6:52:41 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 108, so returning the closest version found: 107```

Comment: ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
 at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
 at path2usacalendar_new.main(path2usacalendar_new.java:48)```